# How to set marker to google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm write this code for show and set the marker to google map:

```
<script>
       var isButtonClick = false;
       function initialize(x, y) {
           var mapProp = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
               zoom: 5,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: myCenter,
               animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
           });
           marker.setMap(map);

       }
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { if (!isButtonClick) initialize(0, 0) });
</script>
```

but marker not show to me!,what happen?

Comment: are you using v3 APi

Comment: myCenter is not defined.

Comment: how to define myCenter?

Comment: is my center coordinates are same as x,y coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.In your question myCenter is not defined.If its a global variable then it might not be initialized or accessible inside the initialize function.I assumed you are trying to add the marker to the points you are passing to the function

```
  var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var isButtonClick = false;
               function initialize(x, y) {
                   var mapProp = {
                       center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
                       zoom: 5,
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   };
                   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
                   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
                       //position: myCenter, //using myCnter global var
                       animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                   });
                   marker.setMap(map);

               }
               google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { if (!isButtonClick) initialize(0, 0) });
```